# Compiling openACC code getting strange error

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, openacc

I'm getting a very strange error message whenever I try to compile the following code using the accull compiler (for compiling openACC). The basic out of the box code that came with the installation compiled and ran just fine, however whenever I try to run code from nvidia

https://github.com/parallel-forall/cudacasts/tree/master/ep3-first-openacc-program

I get the following error. This may have to do with the difference in compilers? Nvidia recommends PGI, but I currently use acull because it's free.

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~/accull/example$ accull -v -o main.x laplace2d.c
 ****************************************
                 _    _ _      _          
                | |  | | |    | |        
   __ _  ___ ___| |  | | |    | |        
  / _` |/ __/ __| |  | | |    | |        
 | (_| | (_| (__| |__| | |____| |____    
  \__,_|\___\___|\____/|______|______|    
 ****************************************
 Release 0.4alpha

* Verbose output
* Output executable name main.x
* Processing laplace2d.c to ./accull_rVpRz/laplace2d.c
* Building laplace2d.c
* Running StS translation
Parsing laplace2d.c ....  laplace2d.c :
159:
160:    StartTimer();
161:    int iter = 0;
162:
163: #pragma acc data copy(A), create(Anew)
164:
165:    while ( error > tol && iter < iter_max )
166:      {
167:        error = 0.0;

ParseError: File: laplace2d.c: 125:  before: acc

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/accull/yacf//bin/c2frangollo.py", line 114, in <module>
    [ast_, prepro_class, lexer_class, parser_class,] = FrontendFactory().parse_with_language_list(original_source, filename, config.CURRENT_LANGUAGES,dirs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/accull/yacf/Frontend/FrontendFactory.py", line 318, in parse_with_language_list
    raise pe
Frontend.Acc.plyparser.ParseError: <stdin>:125: before: acc
! Compilation of laplace2d.c FAILED (no Project directory build )
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -Xcompiler -fopenmp -lrt -lcuda -lOpenCL -lrt -lcuda -arch=sm_20 pi.o _pi_random_1.o /home/ubuntu/accull/frangollo/src/libfrangollo.a -o main.x
* Finished
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~/accull/example$
```

Comment: isn't `#pragma` compiler specific?

Comment: Maybe accull is buggy?

Comment: Are you certain that accULL was built with OpenACC support? I know that the compiler does support OpenACC, but I've never built it before, so I'm not sure whether it requires a configuration option to enable.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/ruyman/accull/overview

Yes I am certain, however I am unable to find any tutorials or examples of using it... This is a fairly tricky problem and I'm afraid this is also the first time I've ever used a compiler specific library.

Comment: If you want an OpenACC-compatible compiler, try GCC 7.1.0 with offloading enabled.  There is good information on the internet about how to compile this:  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Offloading